# Freeze cauliflower?

Tags: vegetables, freezing, cauliflower

I didn't have any issues putting broccoli in the freezer and warming it up again. Worked great. Can you do that with cauliflower, though?

Comment: If you don't like crisp broccoli, you should certainly freeze them so their fibrous strands are made brittle and easily cracked, making the broccoli all mushy and flaccid? OTOH, I love crunchy fresh broccoli. Similarly, cauliflower.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Just chop the cauliflower into florets, blanch for a few minutes, then run under the cold tap to cool quickly, dry thoroughly, and place in a freezer bag.

Answer (score 1):

When I buy packets of frozen veggies, it always has cauliflower in it. So, you can definitely do it. After a quick search on google and checking a couple of links, which all have the same method, [here's](http://www.ehow.com/how_2241655_freeze-cauliflower.html) how.